# "Missing base argument" in HTML::WikiConverter module

Tags: perl, cpan

I have compiled all the modules successfully to run a script called Wikifetch.pl

The Guide can be found here >> http://encodo.com/en/blogs.php?entry_id=73

When I run the script, I get the following output...

```
C:\Strawberry>perl wikifetch.pl
Reading config...
Pending pages:
Main_Page
Done reading config
Fetching/processing: http://wiki.domain.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Missing base argument at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/HTML/WikiConverter.pm line 669.
```

This is the relevant code bit from that file:

```perl
sub __extract_wiki_page {
  my( $self, $uri, $wiki_uri ) = @_;
  return undef unless $wiki_uri;

  if( ref $wiki_uri eq 'Regexp' ) {
    return $uri =~ $wiki_uri ? $1 : undef;
  } elsif( ref $wiki_uri eq 'CODE' ) {
    return $wiki_uri->( $self, URI->new($uri) );
  } else {
    # Ensure $wiki_uri is absolute
    $wiki_uri = URI->new_abs( $wiki_uri, $self->base_uri )->as_string;

    return undef unless index( $uri, $wiki_uri ) == 0;
    return undef unless length $uri > length $wiki_uri;
    return substr( $uri, length $wiki_uri );
  }
}
```

Line 669 is

```
$wiki_uri = URI->new_abs( $wiki_uri, $self->base_uri )->as_string;
```

I'm completely new to Perl, and am lost at this point. I have tried this on Debian/CentOS/Windows with the same results, except for CentOS where I couldn't get everything from CPAN to compile correctly.

Can anybody give me a suggestion?

Comment: That error message is from the URI module. I think it complains because the second argument is empty. There is nothing behind the `base_uri` in your object. Since that seems to be the parser, I believe it could be that you need to configure it, but I didn't read the guide. Anyway, happy new year and good luck with this. :-)